# What is the Debian Way to automatically fetch build dependencies under Debian or Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, debian, dependencies

I recently downloaded the source tarball for a GTK application that I'd like to improve.  It uses the standard `./configure` and `make` build sequence.

The first time through, `configure` reported a bunch of unmet build dependencies, such as `libgnomeui-2.0`.  As I usually do, I had to manually go through and find the Debian `*-dev` package names corresponding to these dependencies... of course the names never match up quite the same, so it gets to be a real hassle.

So what occurred to me is... **are there any helper tools to automatically install the build dependencies listed by the `automake`/`autoconf` configuration files???**

(I already know about the `dpkg-buildpackage` tools, but in this case I am interested in building from a raw distribution-independent source tarball, **not** from the Debian package source.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want [`auto-apt`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=auto-apt) ([manpage](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=auto-apt&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+Sid&format=html&locale=en)).

Comment: Now that's what I'm lookin' for!  Thanks, ephemient!

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome tool to add to my collection. Why does it get no press? +1 for you.

Answer (score 10):

`apt-get build-dep <package>`

Comment: Thanks, John, I am aware of this tool but it only works for packages that have already been "Debianized".  I'm wondering if there is something similar that will do the trick for distro-agnostic tarballs using the standard automake/autoconf system.

Answer (score 0):

short of writing your own script that does an apt-cache search for each package -dev you may be out of luck.